# 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: ionic2

I had some computer issue, and when I tried to `ng serve` my ionic 2 app I received this error:

> c:\xampp\htdocs\themill>ionic serve
>
> > ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve c:\xampp\htdocs\themill
> >     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
>
> 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100"
>   "--livereload-port" "35729" npm ERR! node v6.9.2 npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve:
>   `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100"
>   "--livereload-port" "35729"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts
>   serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port"
>   "35729"'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js
>   and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem
>   with the ionic-hello-world package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm
>   ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!
>   ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100"
>   "--livereload-port" "35729"

I tried to unistall, install, install globally, but it didn't solve.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Windows 10.

Comment: try updating your dependencies and scripts based on this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json

Comment: I just created a new project and updated the files. it did the trick..

Answer (score 15):

In my case the problem was that I was working on a mac and attempted to transfer the project to a windows 10 machine. Steps to follow:

1. In your terminal, navigate to the ionic project's root folder
2. Run this command: `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`
3. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.

I don't know what your case is but in my case, the above steps worked.

If your case is different, perhaps the documentaion here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/app-scripts

will help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply deleting the **node_modules** folder and re-initilaising **npm i**

Not sure how it got into that state in the first place