# 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ionic2

i am updating the ionic version to latest, i try to run the my old project i am getting this errors

'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\user\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2"
 "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--addr
ess" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts
serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.

npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world pac
kage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100
" "--livereload-port" "35729"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\Desktop\demoProj\npm-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the s
pawned command: serve

Comment: can you add package.json to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see my answer to this question:

['ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409396/ionic-app-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/43674863#43674863)

As stated in the answer, my problem was that I was trying to transfer a project from a mac to a windows machine.